# cucumber, capybara, selenium - login test

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to test the login feature on my page, which has a hidden form.
Feature file:

```
Feature: Test login page
  As a visitor to the site
  I can login

  Scenario: User login
    When I go to http://abc.com/
    And I enter username: abc and password: abc
    Then I should see "My Account (abc)"
```

Step_Definitions:

```
When /^I go to (.*)$/ do |path|
  visit path
end

require 'net/http'
When (/^I enter username: abc and password: abc$/) do
  uri = URI('http://www.abc.com/')
  res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri,{ 'username' => 'abc' , 'password' => 'abc'})
  puts res
end

Then /^I should see "(.*)"$/ do |text|
  page.should have_content(text)
end
```

The username and password is correct but this scenario is failing. Am I making the post correct.. Do I need to maintain session or something?
Also the output of res isn't correct, it doesn't even login.

GOT this working thanks to Justin, Solution --> don't use HTTP post, since selenium and capybara are user to imitate user behavior..so follow the flow of user.

Comment: If you are using selenium, why not input the user name and password with selenium? Trying to mix selenium with net/http might not be possible (or at least would require some manual managing of data).

Comment: Okay so you mean use fill_in() and the submit button thing? would that work even if the form is hidden.. or do I need to follow the flow click on login-->fill_in name and password -->click on submit..!
Well I can try both.. Thanks!!

Comment: Alright so I'm using the fill_in() method but it's giving me a javascript error.. I am able to locate the input box by find_field(), but fill_in() isn't working.. It's a modal form.

Comment: It would help if you share the relevant portion of the page's html, your code and the full exception.

Comment: @JustinKo Hey thanks for helping me out man.. finally understood what everything means..!!

Comment: You should post an answer so that others with the same problem will know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah your 1st comment is pretty much the answer, and I have edited the question so as to include the answer.